# How to handle client disconnect from the server when using JSON or protobuf-net

Tags: c#, servicestack, protobuf-net

What's the correct way to handle a client disconnection in a desktop client / selfhosted server ServiceStack application, to be able to trace the times the client didn't receive the responses?
My client sends a request that takes some time on the server, then it disconnects (out of wifi coverage for example) before receiving the response.
I simulate it by killing the client while waiting a long processing response from the server.

With the standard JSON client no error is raised, but I'd like to intercept the disconnection if possibile.

With protobuf-net an Unhandled HttpListenerException is raised here:

```
appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register(ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.ProtoBuf, (reqCtx, res, stream) => ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(stream, res), ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize);
HttpListenerException
```

and I'd like to know how to intercept it (where to put the try/catch). Is it here? in the registration?

Thanks!